# Ant on Windows 7 is trucating a file path string, why?

Tags: windows, perl, ant, path, output

I have a problem with this *ant target*:

```
... ${build} is set.

<target name="x"">
  <echo message="build = ${build}/x.cpp" />
  <apply executable="perl" failonerror="true" parallel="true"
    skipemptyfilesets="true" forwardslash="true">

    <!-- ... other arg tags ... -->

    <arg value="-o"/>
    <arg file="${build}/x.cpp"/>
    <arg value="--error-printer"/>
    <arg value="--force-main"/>
    <arg value="--track-heap"/>
    <arg value="--trap-signals"/>
    <arg value="--trace-stack"/>

    <!-- ... other arg tags ... -->

    <fileset dir="." casesensitive="no">
      <include name="**/*.h"/>
    </fileset>

  </apply>
</target>
```

on execution (on **Windows 7**) I get this:

```
x:
     [echo] build = C:/Program Files/storage/Results/bin/x.cpp
    [apply] Cannot open input file "Files\storage\Results\bin\x.cpp"
```

Why? I've already replaced attribute **file**, with **value** and/or **path** having always the same (wrong) result.

Comment: Try running Ant with the `-v` command-line switch, which should show you exactly what is being passed to the Perl.  But it looks like your issue may be with the Perl.

Comment: Try <arg file="'${build}/x.cpp'"/> to overcome the blank in C:/Program Files means surround with '...'

Comment: AFAIK, some programs have problem handling spaces in paths.

Comment: I guess, Perl is erroneusly "tokenizing" args string.